# ios swift can i read a PPT file in application

Tags: ios, swift, powerpoint

Is there a library to open and read a PPT file from SWIFT.

Comment: better approach, convert PPT into pdf file

Answer (score 2):

There is an official one: [QuickLook Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/QLPreviewController)

Comment: thank, but i doesn't see  PPT or PPS supported format :  A Quick Look preview controller can display previews for the following items:

    iWork documents

    Microsoft Office documents (Office ‘97 and newer)

    Rich Text Format (RTF) documents

    PDF files

    Images

    Text files whose uniform type identifier (UTI) conforms to the public.text type (see Uniform Type Identifiers Reference)

    Comma-separated value (csv) files

Comment: PPT is a microsoft office document...

Comment: ok thank , PPS too ? it'll keep Power Point animation ? or Power Point 
slideshow ? thank again

Comment: Best way to find out it to try downloading a file in your iOS browser or to send it by email. You will see what Quicklook is capable of.

If it cannot display your file, then you're probably out of luck...